# ASP.NET generating Javascript object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to generate a JSON object from server containing data to be cached on client. I placed the following:

```
<script src='Path to js file on server" />
```

At the server, I generated my json data and placed them inside the JS file.

I can see the generated JSON object on the client-side something as:

```
var jsonData = [{}, {}];
```

However, when I try to access `jsonData` object, it says, `undefined`!

Is there another way to generate valid javascript from server side?

Thanks

---

This is the server-side code:

```
var items = List<myObj>();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, Formatting.Indented);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine();
sb.AppendFormat("    var jsonData = {0};", json);

var fileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Scripts/Data.js";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, sb.ToString());
```

As for client side:

`<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Data.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>`

I tried to use this code on the client:

```
alert(jsonData[0].Id);
```

It says, jsonData is undefined!

Regards

Comment: Post a sample json data and the code that tries to use it

Comment: Are you trying post back json or Javascript code? These are two things that are built differently.

Comment: @ianaldo21 json is **javascript** object notation.

Comment: @jrummell JSON is really different thing. In current case this doesn't matter, cause JSON is valid javascript object literal. But not the other way around.

Comment: @jrummell Yep it's javascript object notation. I didn't say they are two different things, they are built (put together) differently.

Answer (score 1):

ASP part is ok, the problem seemed to lie in javascript variable scoping plane. Possible problems:

- You just don't include that js file.
- You're trying to access variable before it is initialized;
- Variable isn't visible in place, you're trying to access it.
- You're not exact in your question and accessing not `jsonData`, but something like `jsonData[0].property`

etc.

UPD: Ok, first two options are excluded. Where are you trying to access this variable? Please, show us a portion of code.